# Angular CLI version is showing as 7.3.9 not 8

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to create a new project in latest version of Angular. I have installed the Angular cli globally using the command `npm install -g @angular/cli`. But when I check the version using command `ng v` it is showing version as `Angular CLI: 7.3.3` and not version 8. Also when a project is created using this CLI, it is showing the Angular project version as `Angular: 7.2.15` . How this can be fixed or this is the latest version ?

Comment: try install it with this command `npm install -g @angular/cli@8.0.0`

Comment: @HachimiAhmedAmine it is showing the same version again.

Comment: i just tried it it install the desired version try `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` then `npm cache clean --force ` then `npm install -g @angular/cli@8.0.0` what is your npm version ?

Comment: @Happy Coder You need to update your @angular/cli and @angular/core by using run this command `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`

Answer (score 0):

Delete the npm folder under the ROAMING folder and clear cache by using `npm cache clean` in command prompt.

And then try to reinstall the npm install and then use this command `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Answer (score 0):

Are you running `ng v` inside an Angular project?

If so, `ng` is showing the CLI installed in your project, and not your global one. Now, if you want to upgrade to `v8`, please adopt the `ng update` schematics and do not upgrade Angular and its libraries manually.

Upgrade the CLI via `ng update @angular/cli` and list the upgradable ones with `ng update`. The other libraries can be upgraded via `npm`.

Also, is recommended to have version control (commit) after each update, as Angular CLI requires the repository to be clean to be able to update.
Ng-joy!

Answer (score 0):

You might be in a directory with a node_modules folder that contained v7 of the Angular CLI and when running ng new myApp it installed Angular v7.

After removing the node_modules folder, and running the command again, npm used the global version of the Angular CLI (v8) and installed v8 of Angular.